# Open Office sequential page numbering left pages

Tags: formatting

I have a document where I have left pages only (Format > Page > Layout settings > left only), so the page numbers start from 2 and increases by 2 every page (2-4-6...). Instead, I need them to be sequential, starting from 1 (1-2-3-4-5...): how can I do that? Thanks.

Version: Apache Open Office 4.1.7, Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

First Google "how to insert page number in Apache Open office Writer". Search under videos and you should find a  good one that I found will show you how to do it. I use the LibreOffice version which updates regularly, but Apache will work also. I do have a version of Word Home & Student 2010 that I purchased years ago. Apache and Libre are free which I do like versus paying for Word which the version of Home & Student is $150. There are forums for Apache Openoffice which can be very useful just Google search Apache Openoffice forums.